# Failed to install ClubDangoV2Released.apk on device: Too many open files

Tags: android

I am getting the following error and don't know why. Some time before, my app was properly installing on a phone but now this error message is fired.

```
[2012-05-16 11:18:56 - ClubDangoV2Released] Failed to install ClubDangoV2Released.apk on device 'S55706733529a': Too many open files
[2012-05-16 11:18:56 - ClubDangoV2Released] com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Too many open files
[2012-05-16 11:18:56 - ClubDangoV2Released] Launch canceled!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seem android insane sometimes.

disabling and enabling of USB Debugging works for me.

if need more detail discussion this link will help
"http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/32865e6b95a9c546?pli=1"

Comment: <a href="http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/32865e6b95a9c546?pli=1" > this link </a>